# Как упростить многочисленные else if?

Tags: php, if

Есть динамические данные от пользователя, которые на сервере необходимо проверять на вхождение в тот или иной диапазон и в зависимости от этого выводить разный результат.

Мне в голову приходит только (пример условный):

```
if($var < 1000) {
    do one
}
else if ($var < 2000) {
    do two
}
else if ($var < 3000) {
    do three
}
.... и т.д.
```

Подскажите, как упростить такую конструкцию?

Comment: @Ипатьев причём тут это? Пример условный, для простоты понимания сути проблемы

Comment: ну вот в таком упрощенном варианте - никак не сократить.  а если знать, как вычисляется результат, то можно. и в этом случае как раз пригодятся знания, полученные во втором классе

Comment: @Ипатьев ничего не вычисляется: пользователь вводит данные, они сравниваются с тем или иным диапазоном

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку автор по какой-то причине упорно не признается, какой именно результат ему надо выводить, придется фантазировать.

В случае, если надо просто вывести некий текст, нам пригодятся такие познания из курса начальной школы, как деление и округление.

```
$results = [
    "Герой пионерского лагеря",
    "Дважды герой пионерского лагеря",
    "Многократный призер куличиков и совочка",
]
$place = floor($var / 1000);
echo $results[$place] ?? 'Завхоз по наградам';
```

Comment: Хорошо, но тут нельзя пропускать `$results[$place] ?? 'Завхоз по наградам'`

Comment: Вот! Работает. Спасибо!